# str_replace function in uploading files

Tags: php

how can i renamed the uploaded file with `str_replace function` ? i wants to remove the `space` with `_`. ANy help with it ? I am using below CODE to upload the file

```
$file1 = 'order_'.$orderId.'_'.$rowsOrder['image_a'];
$file2 = 'order_'.$orderId.'_'.$rowsOrder['image_b'];
$file3 = 'order_'.$orderId.'_'.$rowsOrder['image_c'];
$file4 = 'order_'.$orderId.'_'.$rowsOrder['image_d'];
$path1 = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/'.$file1;
$path2 = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/'.$file2;
$path3 = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/'.$file3;
$path4 = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/'.$file4;
```

---

```
      <tr>";
               if($rowsOrder['image_a'] !=''){
                $message.="<td align='left' style='font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000000;'><a href='http://www.yourdomain.com/files/".$file1."' style='font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:12px; color: #000000; font-weight: normal;' title='http://www.yourdomain.com/'>File1</a></td>";}
                if($rowsOrder['image_b'] !=''){

               $message.= "<td align='left' style='font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000000;'><a href='http://www.yourdomain.com/files/".$file2."' style='font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:12px; color: #000000; font-weight: normal;' title='http://www.yourdomain.com/'>File2</a> </td>";}


             $message.=  "</tr><tr>";


            if($rowsOrder['image_c'] !=''){
                $message.= "<td align='left' style='font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000000;'><a href='http://www.yourdomain.com/files/".$file3."' style='font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:12px; color: #000000; font-weight: normal;' title='http://www.yourdomain.com/'>File3</a></td>";}
                if($rowsOrder['image_d'] !=''){
               $message.= "<td align='left' style='font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000000;'><a href='http://www.yourdomain.com/files/".$file4."' style='font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:12px; color: #000000; font-weight: normal;' title='http://www.yourdomain.com/'>File4</a> </td>";}
               $message.= "</tr><tr>
                        <td colspan='2' align='left' style='font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000000;font-weight: bolder;'><br><br>Thanks,<br><br>
                          <span style='font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000000; font-weight: normal;'><a href='http://www.yourdomain.com/' style='font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:12px; color: #000000; font-weight: normal;' title='http://www.yourdomain.com/'>yourdomain</a></span></td></tr>
```

---

```
$order_image_a='order_'.$orderId.'_'.$filea;
if(!empty($filea)) move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FILE1']['tmp_name'], "../files/$order_image_a");

$order_image_b='order_'.$orderId.'_'.$fileb;
if(!empty($fileb)) move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FILE2']['tmp_name'], "../files/$order_image_b");

$order_image_c='order_'.$orderId.'_'.$filec;
if(!empty($filec)) move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FILE3']['tmp_name'], "../files/$order_image_c");

$order_image_d='order_'.$orderId.'_'.$filed;
if(!empty($filed)) move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FILE4']['tmp_name'], "../files/$order_image_d");
```

If i am uploading the image or any file with gapping in its name, it should be upload with _ in place of gap (Example-- `you files.doc` should be upload by `you_files.doc`). Possible ?

Comment: That's what `str_replace` or `strtr` are meant to do... of course the right place to do it is when you're generating the final filename for `move_uploaded_file`, not when you're outputting said filename.

Comment: Edit my questions with the uploaded file code. Can you please suggest now where to add the function to make it work properly ?

Comment: I am not a huge fan of copy-paste code replication such as this, going from `_a` to `_d`. An array is generally more convenient. The code you posted does not show how `$filea` through `$filed` get their values, so it's a little difficult to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function convertSpecialChars($str) {
    $str = str_replace( " ", "_", $str );
    return $str;
}

$filea = $this->convertSpecialChars($filea);

$order_image_a='order_'.$orderId.'_'.$filea;
if(!empty($filea)) move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FILE1']['tmp_name'], "../files/$order_image_a");
```